# Slick Carousel/Slider - Add navigation as a scrollbar

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I am not sure if this is possible with slick slider to have bottom navigation as **scrollbar** and ***not*** the "**dots**". Of course, this is something that is not provided default in the slick slider but is there anything that we can do to make it work? Similar solution is provided by other JS library such as **sly js**. But i just want to know if it is something that we can do with slick.

[image]